# A function is entire. Show that it's constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function with the property that $|f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)| \leq n^{-n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $f$ is constant.

---

My attempt: So If we can show that $f$ is bounded we can use the Liouville's Theorem to show that it's constant. Now, since $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{1}{n} \leq 1 \implies \frac{1}{n^n} \leq 1^n=1 $. So, $$|f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)| \leq n^{-n} =\frac{1}{n^n} \leq 1$$
So $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is bounded by 1. and since it's bounded and entire it's constant.

---

Is that the right way to show it?

Comment: Do you believe that what you did solves the problem?

Comment: You didn't show $f$ is bounded, you just showed the sequence $f(1/n)$ is bounded.  There's a big difference between those.

Comment: Hint: show that $f(0) = 0$.  If $f$ is not constant, that zero as a finite order.

Comment: $\underset{n\to \infty}{\text{lim}} |f(1/n)| \leq \underset{n\to \infty}{\text{lim}}  \frac{1}{n^n} \implies |f(\underset{n\to \infty}{\text{lim}}\frac{1}{n})| \leq 0 \implies |f(0)|\leq 0$. So $f(0)=0$. Is that the right way to show it?